# SET ENABLE_BROKER demorando muito para executar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Executei o comando `ALTER DATABASE [Banco] SET ENABLE_BROKER;` mas está rodando há mais de 20 minutos e contando. Teria uma forma mais rápida de executar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existe uma maneira mais rápida:

```
ALTER DATABASE [Banco] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

O SQL Server não permite que o comando seja executado até que todas as transações pendentes tenham terminado. Com o comando acima, todas as transações pendentes são canceladas e o serviço `ENABLE_BROKER` é ativado rapidamente.